# Downgrade to ReSharper 9

Tags: c#, resharper

I accidentally installed the newest version of ReSharper (version 10) and recognized afterwards that my license key does not work for this version.
Now I tried to reinstall ReSharper 9 by getting it from the website:

http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206104048-Where-can-I-download-an-old-previous-ReSharper-version-

But the latest installer of ReSharper 9.2 does also only allow me to install ReSharper 10.

Does anybody of you know the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: If I download the 9.2 file from that page and start it it says it will remove version 10 and install 9.2. Are you sure you got the right file? 2015.2?

Comment: Ah! I have executed the file "JetBrains.ReSharper.2015.2.web.exe".
But: The one on the website it is "JetBrains.ReSharperUltimate.2015.2-checked.exe", probably only the web installer redirects the installation to ReSharper 10.

Comment: Think this is a reasonable question -- isn't it covered by "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I confused myself because I used the web-installer of ReSharper 9.2 which forwards to the installation of ReSharper 10.

With the [link on the website](http://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/JetBrains.ReSharperUltimate.2015.2.exe) I was able to download the full installer of version 9.2 and it works!

Comment: Added the link to the latest version RaSharper 9.2.

Comment: Installers for other previous versions of ReSharper can be found [here](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207242355-Where-can-I-download-an-old-previous-ReSharper-version-).